# Bookshelf.js: does fetchAll withRelations work?

Tags: bookshelf.js

Googling this question turns up multiple contradicting answers ("yes"/"no"/"it doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't bring back any relations.") The new documentation doesn't seem to say anything on the matter. Can anyone give a definitive answer (and, if the answer is "no", a workaround, especially for Many-To-Many relations)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean `withRelated`, and not `withRelations`, which is not a valid option.

Yes, it does work. `fetchAll()` is just a passthrough to `collection.fetch()`, which does support that option: https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Collection-instance-fetch